# Remove failure message from multiple assertion failure in NUnit

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I have configured my tests to retry up to x number of times in the event of a failure, to ensure the failure is legitimate and not a fluke during the run. I do not log the error message on the initial failure.

However, I am noticing that if I am running a test, the first test fails, and then the second test passes and I check for any assertion failures via `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message` and notice the first iteration failure is logged and my test is shown as failed, even though the test passed during the second iteration. If both tests fail, I will receive a "Multiple failures or warnings in test."

I would like to retain the final run's failure *only* vs all the failures for all the iterations. Is there a way to remove the initial failure from the `TestContext.CurrentCOntext.Result.Message`?

Edit: I am using NUnit v 3.10.1 and when I downgraded to v.3.4.0 I got the experience I desired without any modification to my code.

Comment: Are you may be retrying the operation in a loop or are you using the NUnit `RetryAttibute`? Behavior would be different in each case.

Comment: @Charlie I am using in a loop and have implemented the solution found here: https://testingrepository.com/retry-failed-tests-in-nunit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NUnit's `[Retry(5)]` attribute on your test to retry the test if it fails. Workarounds like in the link you posted depend on the undocumented internal behavior of NUnit that may change between releases.

Update based on your comment below, if you need to handle unexpected exceptions, wrap the flaky code that might throw in a try/catch block, then do your assertions outside of that block.

```
[Test]
[Retry(5)]
public void TestFlakyMethod()
{
    int result = 0;
    try
    {
        result = FlakyAdd(2, 2);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail($"Test failed with unexpected exception, {ex.Message}");
    }
    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(4));
}

int FlakyAdd(int x, int y)
{
    var rand = new Random();
    if (rand.NextDouble() > 0.5)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    return x + y;
}
```

Adding to the above, you can also use `Assert.DoesNotThrow`, it is a bit cleaner and easier to write.

```
[Test]
[Retry(5)]
public void TestFlakyMethod()
{
    int result = 0;
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => {{
        result = FlakyAdd(2, 2);
    });
    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(4));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Rob! We had the `[Retry(x)]` attribute on our tests previously, but implemented the aforementioned solution since we really wanted to retry tests if there were unhandled exceptions during the execution, and the `[Retry(x)]` attribute does not support this.

Comment: Then we should add an issue to NUnit to handle unexpected exceptions. I will do that :)

Comment: Just a follow-up, it appears there may actually be an issue with the newer version of NUnit (currently v3.10.1). I implemented the above solution, and say I have `[Retry(3)]` and the test fails twice, but passes a third time, my report will show a failure for the test, but when I dig down into the steps it will show a pass status. This does not occur with NUnit v3.4. Further if all three tests fail, I will get the aforementioned "Multiple Failures or Warnings in Test" message rather than the failure from the last test, as expected.